# GRPC With Ruby: How To Call Ruby Methods In App From GRPC Server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, grpc

Am I able to call my ruby backend functions from my grpc server? I have a standard rails app that I am now trying to add grpc to so that outside apps can call a grpc api endpoint to do things through my existing app. Right now I have a standard file structure with app/components, app/models, etc and at the root I have added a /grpc directory with the server, lib, and a protos folder as well. My question is, on the server how can I call my existing ruby functions in my app?

For instance how could I do a call from my grpc server to a class like MyModule::MyClass.store_this_thing_to_the_db(parameter).

Folder Structure Example:
/grpc/grpc_server.rb (I want to call the class from here)
/app/models/my_model (I want to call this class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In grpc_server.rb `require_relative` the rb file containing the `store_this_thing_to_the_db` function and call.